# Django ERROR with tmeplate rendering. Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

Im new to Django (also to stackoverflow too) and im trying to make simple accounts system.
When im "sign out" button to main page im getting this error

```
Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

account/views.py

```
def signout_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/')
```

account/urls.py

```
app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup_view, name='signup'),
    path('signin/', views.signin_view, name='signin'),
    path('signout/', views.signout_view, name='signout'),
]
```

home/templates/home/wrapper.html

```
<form class="logout-link" action="{% url 'account:logout' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Sign out</button>
</form>
```

anyone can help with fixing this problem?

Comment: Well there is no logout, there is a `signout`, so `account:signout`, not `account:logout`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, didnt think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse function gets the name stated at the end of the path funtion in urls.py and retrieves its url

```
path('signup/', views.signup_view, name='signup'),
```

here the name is 'signup' and reverse('signup') will return a 'signup/'. Jinja2's {% url %} tag just calls reverse in django

so to make thing work in your code
just do

```
<form class="logout-link" action="{% url 'account:signout' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Sign out</button>
</form>
```